# How does SMS integration work in Android?

Tags: java, android, sms-gateway, infobip

I m working on an app for SMS integration.
What websites are best for SMS integration?
What should be the approach for implementing in app?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [InfoBip](https://www.infobip.com/en/connecting/api?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=%2Bsms%20%2Bintegration&utm_network=g&utm_matchtype=b&utm_campaign=mena_pakistan_nonbrand&utm_adgroup=mena_pakistan_nonbrand_sms-api_eng_bmm&gclid=Cj0KCQjwuuHdBRCvARIsAELQRQEVWJVwpYiJbdVZyk7fO7c-2mkMUvCffzbPL5q6k0GwfyrffNpYUnwaApr8EALw_wcB) for SMS integration

You can Get there Documentation [Here](https://dev.infobip.com/getting-started)